# How to split a minified angularjs javascript file to multiple files?

Tags: angularjs

I am reviewing an application which uses Angularjs. The application has a single minfied javascript file included. With research, I have identified that the javacript file contains Angular.js source and defines the application's routes, controllers, ec cetera. I need help separating the Angular.js source with other codes in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gulp or grunt for build project. if your using gulp you can create two javascript files using gulp inside gulp.js file. one for dependencies and other one for project source files. And if you need minifi you can use gulp plugin for it. for more details check this link https://gulpjs.com/